# Check success status of POST made in an Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest, http-post, angular-services

In a web application made with Angular I have a controller which call a service to update some data, so there are no object that return from server.
This is the angular code:

```
$scope.movie = Movie.update({ id: $stateParams.id });
```

It works but I want to alert 'Success' if it has update correctly. I've tried adding .success and .error:

```
   .success(function(data) {
      alert('Success update!');
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
      console.error('Repos error', status, data);
    })
```

but console shows me this error: `.success is not a function`

Comment: We need more information about the `Movie` API. Is it an `$resource` object or a promise based API? Does it return an object with a `.then` method or an object with a `$promise` property?

Comment: I have $resource withouth any promise. The server returns this json retult:'ok'

Comment: `.update` is not a default method of a `$resource` object. We need to see the code for your service or an API spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the full code, with the correct structure. I mean, when you use the .success

actually you can use something like this.

```
Movie.update({ id: $stateParams.id }).success(function(data) {
  alert('Success update!');
})
.error(function(data, status) {
  console.error('Repos error', status, data);
})
```

or

```
Movie.update(
  { id: $stateParams.id },
  function(data){
    // do something when success
  }, 
  function (error){
    // do something when error
  }
)
```